# Using a tweet ID as a filename

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to put together a script that will watch twitter for certain keywords, take a picture, and then reply to the initial tweet with the picture. To keep everything straight, I want to use the initial tweet's unique ID as the filename of the picture. I think I am close, but I can't figure out how to make it work. Here is the code:

```
import sys
import tweepy
import time
import threading
import subprocess

consumer_key="X"
consumer_secret="X"
access_key = "X"
access_secret = "X" 

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

class Timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, seconds):
        self.runTime = seconds
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
        time.sleep(self.runTime)

class CountDownTimer(Timer):
    def run(self):
        counter = self.runTime
        for sec in range(self.runTime):
            print counter
            time.sleep(1.0)
            counter -= 1

class CountDownExec(CountDownTimer):
    def __init__(self, seconds, action):
        self.action = action
        CountDownTimer.__init__(self, seconds)
    def run(self):
        CountDownTimer.run(self)
        self.action()

def takePicture():
    new_tweet = CustomStreamListener(status_info)
    subprocess.Popen(['raspistill', '-o', '{}.jpg'.format(new_tweet.id), '-t', '0'])

c = CountDownExec(5, takePicture)

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self,status):
       self.id = status.id
    def on_status(self, status):
       print status.user.id
       print status.user.screen_name
       print status.id
       print status.text
       c.start()

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
sapi.filter(track=['#hashtag @username'])
```

Comment: What is it doing instead? Is there an exception? Is it creating a file with a different name? No name?

Comment: I'm getting this error and I don't know how to pass CustomStreamListener() another argument. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/twitterwatcherwtimertakepicwrightname.py", line 63, in &lt;module>
    sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: If you missed it in the FAQ, when asking a question *always* include what you expected to happen, and what happened instead. Most of us aren't too psychic ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomStreamListener` class has an `__init__` method which takes an `status` argument, but in the line

```
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
```

your make an instance of `CustomStreamListener` without passing that argument so it raises the error

```
__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

This means `__init__` got the `self` argument, but not the other one (`status`).

*To fix the problem you have to pass something as `status` argument on instatiation of the class!*

Comment: It looks like I may have gotten myself in over my head... How can I pass the status argument so that it will work as desired?

Comment: Because I haven't used `tweepy` I can't give your a good answer, but probably you can remove the whole `__init__` function, because you never use `self.id` in your class. Or if you have something to pass e.g. in `s` you can do it so: `sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(s))`

Answer (score 0):

Close...

`subprocess.Popen(['raspistill', '-o', '{0}.jpg'.format(new_tweet.id), '-t', '0'])`

when using string.format() you need to provide a positional number within your curly braces.

Comment: Actually, no you don't. `>>> '{} {}'.format(3, 4)` is perfectly valid syntax. The only necessity for positional or keyword arguments is for duplicating or changing the appearance order, e.g. `'{0}{1}{0}'.format('x', 23)`

Comment: I'm confused then.  I should state that Im using Python 2.6. When I do (I get the following) `>>> '{} {}'.format(3, 4)`
 and then it throws 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    '{} {}'.format(3, 4)
ValueError: zero length field name in format`  I'm seeing in the docs that starting in 2.6 it's added str.format() and even in 3.* they are still saying the following line:   `Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.` http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: It sounds like it's working for the original user (and for you) so I'm assuming it's user error on my part.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It might be that they haven't backported that particular feature to Python 2.6. Are you stuck using 2.6 for some reason? 2.6 was last released in [2008](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/). You should at least be using 2.7 unless there's some business reason.

Comment: yeah we have embedded systems that are using 2.6 =/ can't up my version for the embedded stuff yet (we have libraries that we depend on that aren't fully updated yet).  Even still, the string.format() docs, regardless of version, all say the same thing - `Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument.`  What version are you using that allows you not to put in keyword/numeric index?

Comment: 2.7+ <char limit here>